# Send HTTP.call Json

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I have problems sending a json that will be verified by another server, where then I will get a response from that process has been exist. I'm using HTTP.call, but I have not gotten so far any results in when to functionality.
Already do the tests with postman and everything works me correctly.

Here is a copy of code:

```
    // client side event click button 

      var jsonStr =  JSON.stringify(jsonOBJ);
       Meteor.call("Json", jsonStr, function(error, result){
         if(error){
           console.log("error", error);
         }
         if(result){
            console.log(resul);
         }
       });

    ///server side

      Json(JsonStr) {
       var options = {
      data: JsonStr,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
         }
      try {
       var  url = "https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx-api/4.0/xxxxxx.cgi";
        var result = HTTP.call('POST', url, options )
        return result;
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
      }
    }

    //I must receive something like
    {
        "code": "SUCCESS",
        "error": null,
        "transactionResponse": {
          ....
          ....
         ....
        }
    }
```

That's the answer I'm getting from the server

```
"{"code":"ERROR","error":"Invalid request format","result":null}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem is when using var `str = JSON.stringify (jsonOBJ);` From the client and it passes through `Meteor.call()` when it receives the meteor methods on the server does not arrive with the correct format so the solution is to pass the jsonObj from the client without giving the format and to be received on the server if apply The `JSON.stringify (jsonOBJ)`